# Change dropdown value depending on URL clicked

Tags: uri

Using Drupal 7. From links in an email newsletter, how would it be possible to change the value of a default option value on a webpage? Is there a /?q= that can be used?

email link1 -> my webpage with option 2 selected

email link2 -> my webpage with option 3 selected

by default, webpage dropdown has option 1 selected

Answer (score 1):

[Prepopulate module](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) will take values from the URL and populate a field.
[This page](http://drupal.org/node/228167) has an example for D7.

Comment: Thanks. The option value that I want to change is a Product attribute. How do I get the name of this attribute name?

Comment: That I don't know, but think Devel would help there.